# setting up a stripe hosted sripe checkout with nextJS 13 app router

Tags: stripe-payments, next.js13

im building an online store and im having trouble in some of the final few steps of finishing this project with implementing stripe

ive been trying to follow this guide https://stripe.com/docs/checkout/quickstart

this is my checkout_sessions.ts

```
const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      // Create Checkout Sessions from body params.
      const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
        line_items: [
          {
            // Provide the exact Price ID (for example, pr_1234) of the product you want to sell
            price: 'price_1OIPacLt8ZHkUOknaw8rr1FN',
            quantity: 1,
          },
        ],
        mode: 'payment',
        success_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?success=true`,
        cancel_url: `${req.headers.origin}/?canceled=true`,
      });
      res.redirect(303, session.url);
    } catch (err) {
      res.status(err.statusCode || 500).json(err.message);
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', 'POST');
    res.status(405).end('Method Not Allowed');
  }
}
```

this is my checkout.tsx

```
'use client'
import React from 'react';
import { loadStripe } from '@stripe/stripe-js';

// Make sure to call `loadStripe` outside of a component’s render to avoid
// recreating the `Stripe` object on every render.
const stripePromise = loadStripe(
  process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY
);

export default function PreviewPage() {
  React.useEffect(() => {
    // Check to see if this is a redirect back from Checkout
    const query = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    if (query.get('success')) {
      console.log('Order placed! You will receive an email confirmation.');
    

    if (query.get('canceled')) {
      console.log('Order canceled -- continue to shop around and checkout when you’re ready.');
    }
  }, []);

  return (
    <form action="/api/checkout_sessions" method="POST">
      <section className="bg-white flex flex-col w-400 h-112 rounded-6 justify-between">
        <button type="submit" role="link" className="h-36 bg-blue-600 rounded-4 text-white font-bold border-0 cursor-pointer transition-all duration-200 ease-in-out shadow-md hover:opacity-80">
          Checkout
        </button>
      </section>
    </form>
  );
}
```

i have imported my page preview component appropiately and updated my env.local

but when i click checkout on my local host nothing happens and my stripe product does not display so i think im implementing it wrong if you need more context here it is https://github.com/kalvinyuu/uniqueboutique

Comment: Do you see an error in your web console when you click the button? Have you added logs to your server to ensure you are hitting your endpoint? Do you see any errors in your Stripe logs?

Comment: @bismarck nothing comes my web console i see my secret api key has successful logs but  my publishable one has no successful or failed api requests and i just assume I'd know it would work by seeing products pop up beside the checkout button and on pressing checkout it would take me to a stripe checkout.